# Re-sending MultiPartEmail with apache commons mail

Tags: java, email, apache-commons

**Here's my scenario:**

1. some email sending bean gets called with a bunch of parameters needed for mail construction.
2. it creates MultiPartEmail and queues it for sending which is done by separate thread on the background, caller doesn't care if it was sent or not.
3. the delivering thread picks up queued email instance and does email.send() - so off it goes.
4. when delivery fails, the bean will try re-sending the mail every 5 minutes for three times and then give up.

**Question:**

I can't figure out how to handle #4. What I've got at hand is previously constructed MultiPartEmail instance which failed to be sent. Apparently doing email.send() again throws this:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: The MimeMessage is already built.**

Is there a way to reset this illegal state so that message can be re-used. I don't really have means of creating new instance from scratch - the caller is long gone, and it will make the whole mechanism quite ugly without being able to use already built object. I think I'm missing something very simple here..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see this is an old question, but I just hit the same problem and I found the solution.

When you create an instance of `MultiPartEmail` (or `HtmlEmail`), set its properties, and then invoke the `send()` method, the object will internally invoke the following methods:

- buildMimeMessage()
- sendMimeMessage()

It is ok to invoke `sendMimeMessage()` multiple times, such as a send-with-retry scenario. The problem is that `buildMimeMessage()` can only be invoked once. When you rely on the `send()` method of the base `Email` class, you get the exception found by the original poster.

The solution is to use the two methods I just mentioned when your `Email` object is a `MultiPartEmail`. You explicitly invoke `buildMimeMessage()` once, then invoke `sendMimeMessage()` one or more times.