# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The MimeMessage is already built

Tags: java, email, illegalstateexception

I trying to setup a mail sender in my spring application:

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    private static final String HOSTNAME = "mail.********.com";
    private static final int SMTP_PORT = 25;
    private static final String USERNAME = "*********";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "*********";
    private static final String FROM_ADDRESS = "***********";

    @Bean
    public HtmlEmail mailSender() {
        HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
        email.setHostName(HOSTNAME);
        email.setSmtpPort(SMTP_PORT);
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(USERNAME, PASSWORD));
        email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
        try {
            email.setFrom(FROM_ADDRESS, "Support");
        } catch (EmailException e) {
            throw new BeanCreationException("mailSender", "Failed to create a mailSender", e);
        }
        return email;
    }

}
```

here's the service which I use to send mail:

```
@Service
public class MailService {

    public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());

    private final HtmlEmail mailSender;

    @Autowired
    public MailService(HtmlEmail mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
        this.notificationService = notificationService;
        this.commonDAO = commonDAO;
    }

    @Async
    public void sendMail(int accountId, String subject, String message) {
        log.debug("entered MailService.sendMail");
        String emailId = commonDAO.getEmailId(accountId);
        try {
            mailSender.setSubject(subject);
            mailSender.setHtmlMsg(getMailContent(message, accountId));
            mailSender.addTo(emailId);
            mailSender.addBcc("************");
            mailSender.send();
            sleep(1000L);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error:", e);
        }
    }
}
```

First time after starting tomcat, when I call mailService.sendMail(), mail is sent correctly. Second time onwards, I'm getting error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The MimeMessage is already built.
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.buildMimeMessage(Email.java:1261)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail.buildMimeMessage(MultiPartEmail.java:258)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail.buildMimeMessage(HtmlEmail.java:528)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1427)
    at com.cinch.v2.service.MailService.sendMail(MailService.java:41)
    at com.cinch.v2.service.MailService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d7350403.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I set it up correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re-sending MultiPartEmail with apache commons mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854579/re-sending-multipartemail-with-apache-commons-mail)

Comment: I saw that post already, but I'm confused as to where to call those methods

Answer (score 0):

Look into [HtmlEmail](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/HtmlEmail.html). It has both methods `buildMimeMessage()`, and `sendMimeMessage()`. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854579/re-sending-multipartemail-with-apache-commons-mail), You can call `buildMimeMessage()` once to build your message Mime explicitly, after that you can then call 'sendMimeMessage()` again explicitly any times to send the message.

Try something like this :

```
public static buildEmail( String subject, int accountId){
String emailId = commonDAO.getEmailId(accountId);
            mailSender.setSubject(subject);
            mailSender.addTo(emailId);
            mailSender.addBcc("************");
            mailSender.buildMimeMessage();

}

public static sendEmail(String message, int accountId){
  mailSender.setHtmlMsg(getMailContent(message, accountId));
  mailSender.sendMimeMessage();
}
```

call `buildEmail` once and then you can  call `sendEmail` multiple times

Comment: still confused where in my code I've to call buildMimeMessage() and sendMimeMessage(). I tried calling buildMimeMessage() as last line of MailConfig.mailSender and sendMimeMessage() in MailService.sendMail instead of  mailSender.send(). And I get exception org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: At least one receiver address required. But then If I move buildMimeMessage() to MailService.sendMail(), it will be called multiple times

Comment: I did some changes...if helps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the send() which invokes

- buildMimeMessage()
- sendMimeMessage()

So it is acceptable to call the ***sendMimeMessage()*** multiple times but we should invoke or call the ***buildMimeMessage()*** only once.

You can explicitly invoke ***buildMimeMessage()*** once, then invoke ***sendMimeMessage()*** one or more times.

Comment: please see my comment in the other answer by Yohannes